# Not able to backup of postgres DB from DBeaver

Tags: ubuntu, centos, postgresql, database, database-backup

Hope you are doing great.

We have postgres install on centos server and accessing it through DBeaver from Ubuntu machine.

Whenever we try to take backup of Database it is giving error as "Native client is not specified for connection".

I did search and solution is like "which postgres-> and put result of it in it"

I am not sure about this, do we need to install psql client on ubuntu machine?

Please help

Answer (score 5):

> I did search and solution is like "which postgres-> and put result of
> it in it"

Not on Ubuntu. `which postgres` will typically print nothing. The command that DBeaver wants are `pg_dump` to create backups, and `pg_restore` to restore.

These commands can be installed with `sudo apt install postgresql-client`.

Then in DBeaver, go to  Database->Driver Manager, choose "PostgreSQL" then "Edit" then navigate to the "Native Client" tab, then "Add Home" and choose `/usr/bin` as the location, since it's where `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` are installed. Alternatively, you may choose `/usr/lib/postgresql/<version>/bin` where `<version>` is your PostgreSQL version, if you have several versions installed and the automatic selection by `/usr/bin/pg_dump` doesn't work for you.